# find element's value based on node's position in xml document

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

```
<OverallReport>
    <Results>
       <Data1>
            <a>-30 </a>
            <b>400</b>
       </Data1>
       <Data2>
            <MoreData>
                    <c>2</c>
                    <d>100</d>
           </MoreData>
           <MoreData>
                    <c>4</c>
                    <d>200</d>
           </MoreData>
       </Data2>
   </Results>
   <Results>
       <Data1>
            <a>-50</a>
            <b>600</b>
       </Data1>
       <Data2>
           <MoreData>
                    <c>2</c>
                    <d>200</d>
           </MoreData>
           <MoreData>
                    <c>6</c>
                    <d>500</d>
           </MoreData>
      </Data2>
   </Results>
   <Results>
       <Data1>
            <a>-50</a>
            <b>600</b>
       </Data1>
       <Data2>
           <MoreData>
                    <c>2</c>
                    <d>300</d>
           </MoreData>
           <MoreData>
                    <c>6</c>
                    <d>900</d>
           </MoreData>
      </Data2>
   </Results>
</OverallReport>
```

I have an XML document, such as the above, that contains any number of Results nodes and any number of MoreData nodes. I must find the results node that contains two specific values (e.g. a=-50, b=600), and within that node, find the value of ‘d’ if ‘c’ is equal to a specific value. As well, there are various results nodes that may have the same a, b, and c, and I will need to find the 'x' one. So, if (a=-50, b=600, c=6, x=0) the value of d I'm looking for is 500 . If (a=-50, b=600, c=6, x=1) the value of d I'm looking for is 900.

I have a related question posted, with a working answer, but this is a bit more advanced so I decided to create a  new question. The way I am currently finding d:

```
string wantedA = "-50";
string wantedB = "600";
string wantedC = "6";
string x=1;

string xpath = string.Format("OverallReport/Results[Data1/a={0} and Data1/b={1}]/Data2/MoreData[c={2}]/d",
wantedA, wantedB, wantedC);

XmlNode nodeD = document.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
Console.WriteLine(nodeD.InnerText);
```

Again, I'm new to Xml and any help or hints will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there are some mistakes in your xml, it should be:

```
<OverallReport>
    <Results>
       <Data1>
            <a>-30 </a>
            <b>400</b>
       </Data1>
       <Data2>
            <MoreData>
                    <c>2</c>
                    <d>100</d>
           </MoreData>
           <MoreData>
                    <c>4</c>
                    <d>200</d>
           </MoreData>
       </Data2>
   </Results>
   <Results>
       <Data1>
            <a>-50</a>
            <b>600</b>
       </Data1>
       <Data2>
           <MoreData>
                    <c>2</c>
                    <d>200</d>
           </MoreData>
           <MoreData>
                    <c>6</c>
                    <d>500</d>
           </MoreData>
      </Data2>    // was <Data2> - slash added
   </Results>
   <Results>
       <Data1>
            <a>-50</a>
            <b>600</b>
       </Data1>
       <Data2>
           <MoreData>
                    <c>2</c>
                    <d>300</d>
           </MoreData>
           <MoreData>
                    <c>6</c>
                    <d>900</d>
           </MoreData>
      </Data2>    // was <Data2> - slash added
   </Results>
</OverallReport>
```

Secondly, you have to change type of `x` from `string` to `int`:

```
string wantedA = "-50";
string wantedB = "600";
string wantedC = "6";
int x = 1; // or 0
```

Finally, you should find all nodes which meet your criteria and then select one which depends on `x`:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes(xpath);            
Console.WriteLine(nodes[x].InnerText);
```

So, your code should be:

```
    string wantedA = "-50";
    string wantedB = "600";
    string wantedC = "6";
    int x = 1; // or 0

    string xpath = string.Format("OverallReport/Results[Data1/a={0} and Data1/b={1}]/Data2/MoreData[c={2}]/d",
    wantedA, wantedB, wantedC);

    XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes(xpath);            
    Console.WriteLine(nodes[x].InnerText);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the entire XPath in parens and apply position index filter/predicate, for example :

```
(OverallReport/Results[Data1/a=-50 and Data1/b=600]/Data2/MoreData[c=6]/d)[2]
```

Notice that XPath index starts from `1` instead of `0` like in C#. So the above XPath expression would return `900` given sample XML in question as test document.

Comment: Thank you so much!